# Aceitar string somento com letras, números ou pontos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando o plugin Jquery Validate para validar nomes de usuário do facebook, e por padrão pode ter letras,números e pontos.

```
Ex: joao, joao22, joao.maluco22
```

Como validar isso com jQuery Validate?

O padrão dos métodos são assim:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Somente letras");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adiciona um método ao validator

```
$.validator.addMethod("validarUsuario", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional( element ) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$/.test( value );
}, 'Informe um usuário válido.');
```

Adiciona uma regra ligada a uma classe, assim os inputs com a classe `validar-usuario` serão validados por essa nova regra `validarUsuario`. Você pode adicionar mais de uma regra também, por exemplo, tornar o campo obrigatório, adicionando também a regra `required`.

```
$.validator.addClassRules("validar-usuario", {
    "validarUsuario": true
});
```

Seu input fica assim:

```
<input type="text" class="validar-usuario" id="ipt_usuario">
```